# How does Codie, Vociferous Codex work with effects that force you to cast a permanent spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Codie, Vociferous Codex states:

> You can’t cast permanent spells.

Sol Talisman is a permanent with suspend. Suspend states:

> When the last (time counter) is removed, cast (this spell) without paying its mana cost.

If I have a Codie, Vociferous Codex on the battlefield and I remove the last time counter from a Sol Talisman, is the Sol Talisman cast, since you have no choice in whether or not it is cast? Or does Codie win, and disallow the casting, leaving Sol Talisman permanently exiled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your suspended Sol Talisman cannot be cast (and it stays exile)**.

One of the Magic Golden Rules specifies that "can't" always overrides "can."

> 101.2. When a rule or effect allows or directs something to happen, and another effect states that it can’t happen, the “can’t” effect takes precedence.

The [full comprehensive rules](https://media.wizards.com/2021/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020211115.pdf) for Suspend confirms that if the spell isn't cast it remains exiled (with no time counters). Here are the relevant rules regarding Suspend (702.62) (emphasis mine)

> 702.62a Suspend is a keyword that represents three abilities. The first is a static ability that functions while the card with suspend is in a player’s hand. The second and third are triggered abilities that function in the exile zone. “Suspend N—[cost]” means “If you could begin to cast this card by putting it onto the stack from your hand, you may pay [cost] and exile it with N time counters on it. This action doesn’t use the stack,” and “At the beginning of your upkeep, if this card is suspended, remove a time counter from it,” and “When the last time counter is removed from this card, if it’s exiled, play it without paying its mana cost **if able. If you can’t, it remains exiled.** If you cast a creature spell this way, it gains haste until you lose control of the spell or the permanent it becomes.”

So since Codie prevents your from casting permanent spells, you can never cast your Sol Talisman (even from exile via suspend).

As an aside, Codie's restriction also prevents you from even suspending the card in the first place.

> 702.62c While determining if you could begin to cast a card with suspend, take into consideration any effects that would prohibit that card from being cast.